# When Web Forms won't be supported from Microsoft

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We are going to create new application using Web Forms and we want to know when Web Forms (ASPX pages) Technology going to be obsolete or not be supported from Microsoft.

Comment: About 2 years ago, actually. ASP.NET dropped support for all legacy ASP.NET platforms (WebForms, old-school MVC, old-school Web API, WCF ASP.NET compatibility) when ASP.NET Core 1.0 came out in 2016.

Comment: As for "obsolete", it's been obsolete for quite a few years. I wouldn't say since ASP.NET MVC 1.0 came out, but new development stopped soon after

Comment: @Dai: **NO** WebForms continues to be supported (and will continue to be supported as long as .NET Framework 4.8 is (and, since that's considered a component of Windows...).  VS 2022 even has a new WebForms designer: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2022-17-2-is-now-available/#web-live-preview-for-asp-net-framework

Comment: @Flydog57 Right, but none of that means that WebForms should be considered for any new development projects. Microsoft is keeping WebForms alive because they have to, not because they want to - and WebForms’ “Postback” and “server-side-events” concept are still _objectively bad_.

Answer (score 7):

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/aspnet
So WebForms is part of .Net Framework.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies

“**.NET Framework 4.8 is the last version of .NET Framework.** .NET Framework is serviced monthly with security and reliability bug fixes. **.NET Framework will continue to be included with Windows, with no plans to remove it.** You don't need to migrate your .NET Framework apps, but for new development, use .NET 5 or later.”

So it's baked into Windows at this point if you want to use it. Everyone will discourage you from using it, as you are essentially mastering out-of-vogue and increasingly obsolete technology, and maybe not doing your career any favors. But if, like me, you have some huge WebForms app for which there is no time nor money to rewrite, then you can at least rest assured that it will continue to run on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft will be continuing to support ASP.Net WebForms for some time to come since much of it's functionality is based into the core .Net Framework. There are several locations to get information on which ASP.Net features/technologies such as ASP.Net MVC 4 will be going out of support soon. https://www.asp.net/support lists many of the technologies. For ASP.Net Webforms, it's tied to the Framework versions as best as I understand. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=.net%20framework

Comment: That's not quite right. All new development goes to ASP.NET Core which doesn't provide Web Forms.

Comment: Correct. New development thought does not equal end of support and the question was asked about support, not about new development.